# Django -- Checking input type, display error message if wrong

Tags: python, django, input

I'm new to learning Django/Python and hoping for some assistance. This is for an assignment and I'm stumped on the last part. We need to take input from the user (name as string; weight, height inches, and height feet as ints) and calculate the bmi, displaying {{name}}'s bmi is {{bmi}}

I have that part working fine, but the second part of what I have to do is check that the input is valid, that is not a string where it should be an int, and not a negative number. I am supposed to put this into the class. I was reading about is_valid() but I haven't used that yet and am not entirely sure how to do it. I am guessing it will have to be an if else statement.

**views.py**

```
class Home(View):
  def get(self, request):
      return render(request, 'home.html')
  def post(self, request):
      n = str(request.POST["name"])
      w = int(request.POST["weight"])
      hi = int(request.POST["heightinches"])
      hf = int(request.POST["heightfeet"])
      h = (hf*12) + hi
      bmi = (703*w) / (h*h)
      return render(request, 'response.html',{"name":n,"heightinches":hi,"heightfeet":hf,"weight":w,"height":h,"bmi":bmi}
```

**home.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head><title>Home</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Repl.it</h1>
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
  name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/> <br>
  weight: <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight"/> pounds<br>
  height: <input type="text" name="heightinches" id="heightinches"/> inches<br>
  <input type="text" name="heightfeet" id="heightfeet"/> feet<br>
  <input type="submit"/>

  
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**response.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head><title>Home</title></head>
  <body>
  {{name}}'s BMI is {{bmi|floatformat:2}}

  <p><a href="home.html">Back</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for the help! My instructor isn't the easiest to get ahold of so I'm hoping I'll have better luck here :S

Comment: Read through the documentation on [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) and [The Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form), of course you can use if-else but a form would handle the validation / cleaning for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Django for an amount of time now. Django offers an in-depth forms library built into the base Django library.

I would strongly recommend following this guide on how to set this up.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/

If you require custom validation, you can add a function to the bottom of your InputForm class to check this and raise a ValidationError if it does not pass:

```
def check_google_url(self):
    url = self.cleaned_data['url']
    if "https://google.com" not in url:
        raise forms.ValidationError("URL does not match Google! Please copy and paste the full google.com URL.")
    else:
        return url
```

Once you have a form setup, you could use crispy forms to define 'error' and 'required' css classes for this page. Crispy Forms - https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Div(
    'negatives',
    'positives',
    'learnings',
    'rating',
    css_class="final-feedback",
    required_css_class="error",
    error_css_class="error",
    title="Final Comments",
    ),
)
```